# Logging within Program.cs

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to get an ILogger inside Program.cs Main method? I want to pass it on to a service that's created inside that method.

I've only found this on SO [How do I write logs from within Startup.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287648/how-do-i-write-logs-from-within-startup-cs) , but that's logging within Startup.cs.

Comment: See the official docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/#log-in-programcs

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Accidentally stumbled upon the answer after googling a bit more.

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var logFactory = new LoggerFactory()
            .AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug)
            .AddDebug();

            var logger = logFactory.CreateLogger<Type>();

            logger.LogInformation("this is debug log");
        }
    }
}
```

Kudos to https://askguanyu.wordpress.com/2016/09/26/net-core-101-e06-net-core-logging/

Comment: You should probably take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45126149/configuring-dependencies-e-g-logging-in-program-cs-when-ef-migrations-dont-g) so you can use the same logger instance in the rest of your application.

Comment: @anserk Don't think that's possible, since ILogger instances are generically typed (i.e. `ILogger<Startup>`).

Comment: This no longer works for .NET Core 3.1 and up.

Comment: See @RickAndMSFT answer below for .Net 6. You can access Logger directly via `Builder.WebApplication.Logger` now.

Answer (score 19):

This is how I managed to get the `ILogger` interface configured in `Startup.cs` (in my case Log4Net) working when inside `Program.cs`:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = BuildWebHost(args);

    ILogger logger = host.Services.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();

    try
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Starting web host");

        host.Run();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogCritical(ex, "Starting web host failed.");
    }
}
```

- Add `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` so that the generic type in `GetService` works as expected.

Comment: Oddly enough, while I can get the logger inside the catch to work with NLog, I can't with Serilog. I've even created a new LoggerConfiguration() and called .CreateLogger() on it, and set it up just like I do before the try, and it won't log to serilog in the catch. The logger statement in the try logs correctly, as do all of the other places I log in other classes.

Answer (score 9):

See the official doc [Log in Program.cs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/#log-in-programcs)

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
app.Logger.LogInformation("Adding Routes");
app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
app.Logger.LogInformation("Starting the app");
app.Run();
```

Comment: But how to use the logger before the application is built?

Comment: before app is built the logging is configured so it doesn't exist. You can use std Console.WriteLine() or bootstrap serilog.

Answer (score 8):

New in .NET Core 6 (I have no idea if this was new to .NET core 6, 5 or 3).

```
var logger = LoggerFactory.Create(config =>
    {
        config.AddConsole();
        config.AddConfiguration(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    }).CreateLogger("Program");
```

This was my simple starting point, you don't actually have to pickup the Configuration section for logging, but I figured it makes sense. But you do need to specify an output; Console, although default for DI is not assumed in the factory.

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me in combination with `serilog` based on the default template of `Program.cs` (**.NET 6.0**), was nearly the same approach as the one of Leniel Maccaferri.

```
ILogger logger = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
logger.LogInformation("This is a testlog");
```

Comment: Where does "builder" come from and what is its type?

Comment: @NickG see official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#log-in-programcs - 'WebApplication.CreateBuilder'

Comment: in .Net 8 rc2 worked

Answer (score 1):

Following helped me to add logger for program.cs as well as for any of the static classes

```
private static void TemporaryLogger(string methodName, string lineNumber)
    {
        var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole());
        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(string.Empty);
        logger.LogInformation($"Test Logger for  class className: Identifier - {methodName} : Line number - {lineNumber}");
    }
```

Comment: This approach has some performance issues. Calling `LoggerFactory.Create` every time you want to log is wasting cycles because under the covers it uses DI to create an ILogger, and then just throws it away after logging a single message. It would be better to only do it once and cache the ILogger instance.

Answer (score -2):

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Logging.AddLog4Net();
```

Above worked for me in .net 6

Thanks to: https://onloupe.com/blog/does-log4net-work-on-net6/