# Building intermediate IServiceProvider for use in custom IConfigurationProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp-net-config-builders

Problem Statement: I have a custom `IConfigurationProvider` that requires a *complex* service to function properly.  This *complex* service would, naturally be registered to the applications `IServiceProvider`.  I want to use `IServiceCollection`/`IServiceProvider` facilities in conjunction with `IConfigurationProvider` to avoid manual new of this *complex* service, and to re-use registration code that would otherwise be written in the normal part of the DI container building portion of the app.

I've found plenty of documentation describing the troubles of needing an `IServiceProvider` in an `IConfigurationProvider`.  [This is the closest thing that felt ok to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64556896/how-to-access-di-inside-custom-configurationprovider), and is the inspiration for this post.

Here's my approach at a high level

1. Build the configuration up enough to construct the intermediate `IServiceProvider`
2. Build the intermediate `IServiceProvider`
3. Build the rest of the configuration via custom `IConfigurationProvider`'s that require special services, retrieved via `intermediateServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();`
4. Transfer the registrations and, specifically, singleton objects, from the intermediate `IServiceCollection`/`IServiceProvider` to the final `IServiceCollection`/`IServiceProvider`.  This will help avoid re-registering things in step #5 and will help avoid second instances of singletons in the final `IServiceProvider`.
5. Register the final set of services to complete the final `IServiceProvider`, using configuration that was injected in step #4.

#1,#2,#3,#5 are simple enough.  #4 is where I'm hitting roadblocks.  My first attempt at #4 was the following

```cs
    foreach (var sd in intermediateServiceCollection)
    {
        if (sd.Lifetime == ServiceLifetime.Singleton)
        {
            // Externally owned
            if (sd.ImplementationInstance != null)
            {
                finalServiceCollection.AddSingleton(sd.ServiceType, sd.ImplementationInstance);
            }
            // Provide a factory function to delegate to intermediate service provider
            else
            {
                finalServiceCollection.AddSingleton(sd.ServiceType, 
                    s => intermediateServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(sd.ServiceType));
            }
        }
        // Transient/scoped service descriptors can be forwarded along without issue
        else
        {
            finalServiceCollection.Add(sd);
        }
    }
```

[As documented here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/41050), registering open-generic types with a factory function is not supported.

After stumbling upon this limitation, my latest approach looks like:

```cs
    foreach (var sd in intermediateServiceCollection)
    {
        if (sd.Lifetime == ServiceLifetime.Singleton)
        {
            // Externally owned
            if (sd.ImplementationInstance != null)
            {
                finalServiceCollection.AddSingleton(sd.ServiceType, sd.ImplementationInstance);
            }
            // Provide a factory function to delegate to intermediate service provider
            else if (!sd.ServiceType.IsGenericType)
            {
                finalServiceCollection.AddSingleton(sd.ServiceType, 
                    s => intermediateServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(sd.ServiceType));
            }
            else
            {
                // Simply adding the service descriptor to the final service collection
                // opens the door for singleton instances to be created again
                //
                // In reality, this may be configurable to raise an exception to signal
                // to our developers they need to avoid registering open-generics in the 
                // bootstrapping portion of the app.  But, this may serve it's purpose
                // if you can live with multiple instances of a singleton.
                finalServiceCollection.Add(sd);
            }
        }
        // Transient/scoped service descriptors can be forwarded along without issue
        else
        {
            finalServiceCollection.Add(sd);
        }
    }
```

Obviously, my current implementation is not perfect as it allows for multiple singleton instances if that singleton is registered as an open-generic.  But, with an understood limitation of bootstrap registration being non open-generic types, I can "successfully" create an intermediate `IServiceProvider` for use within `IConfigurationProvider`'s and transfer it to the final `IServiceProvider`.

1. Can anyone provide inspiration that can lead to a complete implementation for #4, specifically around transferring open-generic registrations?
2. Is the assumption that this approach is reasonable total nonsense and I should opt for a different pattern to configure my application?

Comment: Maybe create a separate service collection for this configuration provider that is separate from the one the application is using. This is a chicken and egg problem. Split the worlds and don't copy registrations.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same configuration provider for intermediate and final service provider and you need the same services in the final service provider as within the intermediate one, why don't you put your whole setup logic of the intermediate provider into a method that gets the target builder as parameter? Then you can first call it to setup your intermediate one and later another time to setup your final provider.

In that case you don't need any kind of reflection and you can use all available extension helper class or own logic to setup the configuration provider.

Comment: It's not that I need a configuration provider for two equal sets of services, I need a set of services (intermediate services) to enable a configuration provider to enable the creation of more services.  The intermediate services and the services created with configuration from the configuration provider makeup the list of final services used in the app.  I've updated my question to include a step #5 to make this clearer.