# 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[Application.Startup]' while attempting to activate 'Application.Startup'.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.0 application. I am getting error as

'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[Application.Startup]' while attempting to activate 'Application.Startup'.'

I Know that ILogger is not default registered in ASP.NET Core 3.0 Application. Below is my code for Program.cs and Startup.cs for reference

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
          {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
          })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
          webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<AnyClass>>();
        services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger), logger);
        ...
     }
```

Please can anyone help me with this error, What I am doing wrong in my case ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write logs from within Startup.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287648/how-do-i-write-logs-from-within-startup-cs)

Comment: No As said in the link for ASP.NET 3.0 followed but still the same error

Comment: part of the answer in that question is in regards to ASP.NET Core 3.0

Comment: Why are you resolving the logger just to register it as a Singleton anyways?

Comment: Empty all the code out of your ConfigureServices

Comment: @Claius If I empty all the code from ConfigureServices still it throws error

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue by using your code.Could you share more details?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#create-logs-in-the-startup-class writing logs before completion of the DI container setup in the Startup.ConfigureServices method is not supported.

You cannot do `var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<AnyClass>>();` since the DI container is not configured yet, at that stage.

More information on the link provided.

Comment: I tried commenting those lines as well, Still it throws error on Line HostBuilder.Build().Run() when I debug

Comment: You cleared all providers by doing this `logging.ClearProviders();` and did not add any back. Try adding `logging.AddConsole();` and see how it goes. You might need this nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console for this extension method.

Comment: ILoggingBuilder does not contain definition of AddConsole() Where logging is ILoggingBuilder

Comment: AddConsole() gets available while I added In .ConfigureLogging but still the error exists In this case var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<AnyClass>>(); was commented