# How do I log an exception from ConfigureServices in Startup in an ASP.NET Core 3.0 application

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46298052) we cannot resolve a logger to log messages or exceptions from the `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup`. This is a problem for me because I have code in `ConfigureServices` which is written to throw exceptions if required settings are missing. Is there any other way that I can log that exception?

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions inside `ConfigureServices` method can be thrown from two different sources:

1. From the `ConfigureServices` method code itself.
2. From Factory methods passed to the DI container.

Example:

```
services.AddScoped<IDependency>(sp =>
{
   // Any Exception from here
});
```

I pointed these two scenarios because I have found that they resolve using different approaches.

Scenario 1:
Same approach used in this answer [Answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68184267/4117773) (using that startup class, maybe adjusting how the exception is handled inside Configure method)

Scenario 2:
This scenario is even harder because the try/catch used in scenario 1 doesn't catch exceptions thrown from Factory methods. But in those cases we have access to the `ServiceProvider` so we can handle exception inside each factory method with something like this.

```
services.AddScoped<IService>(sp =>
    {
        var httpContext = sp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;
        var logger = sp.GetService<ILogger<IService>>();                
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Text Exception");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log
            logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
            // status error
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
            httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }                
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a way to log an exception thrown from `ConfigureServices`. It's just a bit of hack. Maybe it's not a terrible hack. You decide.

`ConfigureServices` runs before `Configure`. We *can* inject a logger into `Configure`. So the hack is to hang on to the exception we throw in `ConfigureServices`, then log and rethrow it from the `Configure` method.

It's easiest to see it all at once, so here's a sample `Startup`:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    private Exception _configureServicesException;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        try
        {
            // Configure all of your services
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _configureServicesException = ex;
        }
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_configureServicesException != null)
            {
                ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(_configureServicesException).Throw();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(
                                ex,
                                "Exception thrown when starting application in {Environment} environment",
                                env.EnvironmentName);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what's been added:

- `private Exception _configureServicesException;` is a field for storing an exception thrown from `ConfigureServices`.
- If `ConfigureServices` throws an exception, we store it in that field and continue without rethrowing it.
- We've added an `ILogger` argument to `Configure` so that the runtime will inject a logger. (More on that in a moment.)
- When the runtime calls `Configure`, then if an exception was thrown from `ConfigureServices`, we'll rethrow it. In this example we'll catch, log, and rethrow any exception thrown in `Configure`, including the one that we captured from `ConfigureServices`.

All of this assumes that we've configured logging before this point. How to that is detailed in [this Microsoft documentation - "Capture logs within ASP.NET Core startup code"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#capture-logs-within-aspnet-core-startup-code).

Reproducing the example from that page:

```cs
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((context, builder) =>
                {
                    // Providing an instrumentation key is required if you're using the
                    // standalone Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights package,
                    // or when you need to capture logs during application startup, for example
                    // in the Program.cs or Startup.cs itself.
                    builder.AddApplicationInsights(
                        context.Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTIONSTRING"]);

                    // Capture all log-level entries from Program
                    builder.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>(
                        typeof(Program).FullName, LogLevel.Trace);

                    // Capture all log-level entries from Startup
                    builder.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>(
                        typeof(Startup).FullName, LogLevel.Trace);
                });
```

...the key detail being that we're configuring logging so that the runtime can inject a logger when we call

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
```

Comment: Are you not able to capture exception on `Build`  or host `Run*` and log via an external logger at the program level? This is an interesting approach/hack you have here.

Comment: I'd have to see exactly what you're referring to. Perhaps you could supply a different answer. I'm not thrilled to death with mine which is why I call it a hack. But it's easy to read and understand. There's exactly one point in the application where I need to log before logging has been configured.