# Logger becomes disposed between Startup and ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I've created a logger which should log anything during start of application run. And I wanted it to persist between `Startup` and `ConfigureServices`. I store it in the property similar to configuration

Here is the code

```cs
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;

    using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
    {
        builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Error);
        builder.AddEventLog(s =>
        {
            s.LogName = "MyLogName";
            s.SourceName = "MySource";
        });

        // add some other persisting logger
    });
    StartupLogger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Startup>();
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public ILogger StartupLogger { get; } // Logger exists here when breakpoint is in ConfigureServices

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        
    StartupLogger.LogError("Failed to do something"); // <-- throws exception
}
```

This is the error I get. Looks like inner logger gets disposed in the process

> Message: "An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'EventLogInternal'.

Full stack

> 'StartupLogger.LogError("Failed to do something")' threw an exception of type 'System.AggregateException'
> Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
> HResult: -2146233088
> HelpLink: null
> InnerException: {"Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'EventLogInternal'."}
> InnerExceptions: Count = 1
> Message: "An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'EventLogInternal'.)"
> Source: "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging"
> StackTrace: "   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.ThrowLoggingError(List`1 exceptions)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1.Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions.Log(ILogger logger, LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, Exception exception, String message, Object[] args)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions.LogError(ILogger logger, String message, Object[] args)"
> TargetSite: {Void ThrowLoggingError(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Exception])}

Surely I have a wrong approach here. Appreciate some guidance.

Comment: I'm thinking that when the logger factory gets disposed at the end of the `Startup` constructor, it disposes any associated loggers. It's the only logical explanation that I can see.

Comment: Why do you add `using` to the variable declaration, when you want it to persist outside of the scope of the method?

Comment: @gunr2171 good eye. Gonna try this now. May be I copied from some example. don't remember

Comment: Do you really need to log within `ConfigureServices`? Or do you need to log the values you are assigning to classes that follow the options pattern? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @JeremyLakeman in this `ConfigureServices` I have a lot of custom initialization stuff. Reading custom settings values and decrypting them. dynamically wire dependency injection and more. Custom authentication wire up. etc

Answer (score 4):

Change the [using declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using) `using var loggerFactory` to the ordinary one - it leads to the disposal of the `loggerFactory` at the end of scope (`Startup` constructor in this case):

```cs
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;

    var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
    {
        builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Error);
        builder.AddEventLog(s =>
        {
            s.LogName = "MyLogName";
            s.SourceName = "MySource";
        });

        // add some other persisting logger
    });
    StartupLogger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Startup>();
}
```

Also note that `Startup` `Configure` method [supports dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46298052/2501279) and if it feasible for you to move your initialization logic there - you can just inject `ILogger<Startup>` into this method:

```cs
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    // ...
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, , IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
    {
        logger.LogError("Failed to do something"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: yes. This works. Blur vision. Not sure how I arrived to the `using` there. Must be some copy/paste. been weeks. Only when ran into "unhappy" scenario, it manifested

Comment: @T.S. happens even to the best of us =) Also please see the update, JIC.

Comment: good point on the DI on startup. Ha!!! I knew that I don't know something, So, the app will wire me up a logger per configurations in app settings/user secrets, correct? Will try right now!

Comment: @T.S. yes, it should.

Comment: no, it did not do it
`System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ConfigureServices method must either be parameterless or take only one parameter of type IServiceCollection.'`

Comment: @T.S. yes, my bad, it is supported only in `Configure` call. Is it suitable to move the initialization logic to `Configure`?

Comment: Potentially. I will have to give it a try tomorrow. Depends what runs first. I'll need to research. Right now my code is working for check in. No show stopper. Your tips are greatly appreciated!! +1

Comment: @T.S. was glad to help! `ConfigureServices` runs first and then `Configure` before the app start.

Comment: wait, `public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)` runs first. then `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` - this I know.

Comment: @T.S. yes, `Startup` ctor will run first for sure, then `Startup.ConfigureServices` then `Startup.Configure`.

Comment: phew... yes. The class is `Startup`. of course, this is a constructor. But may be not - I need services there for my initializations. I will need to see

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to log within ConfigureServices? Or do you need to log the options you are updating?

For anything that follows the [Options Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0), (and all built in services do) you can configure the options in a lambda, injecting other services;

```cs
services.AddMvc();
services.AddOptions<MvcOptions>()
    .Configure<ILogger<Startup>>((options, logger) => {
        options.something = X;
        logger.LogInformation($"... {X} ...");
    });
```

Note that the `services.AddMvc(options => {...});` extension method is internally doing something [very similar](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/0402550585f54e88707af55652111ace793ef27f/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/src/OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L54).

Or perform configuration via dedicated services;

```cs
services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>, ConfigureMvcOptions>();

public class ConfigureMvcOptions : IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>{
    private readonly ILogger<ConfigureMvcOptions> logger;
    public ConfigureMvcOptions(ILogger<ConfigureMvcOptions> logger){
        ...
    }
    
    public void Configure(MvcOptions config)
    {
        options.something = X;
        logger.LogInformation($"... {X} ...");
    }
}
```

Or perhaps one service for everything;

```cs
services.AddSingleton<ConfigureEverything>();
services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>>(p => p.GetService<ConfigureEverything>());
services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<SomethingElse>>(p => p.GetService<ConfigureEverything>());
// etc

public class ConfigureMvcOptions : 
    IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>,
    IConfigureOptions<SomethingElse>,
    // etc
```

Obviously this is less flexible that just creating a startup logger. As in all the above cases, the configuration methods are only called on first use, once the generic host is starting.

Comment: This is interesting!!! Today I solved my issue (removed using). And I will check this out tomorrow. Thank you