# How to inject NLog in DI in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, nlog

I have multiple projects and I want to add NLog to all my projects so I created one common project and I want to use it as a nuget package in other projects.

I am configuring NLog programmatically. I want to inject my package class in the dependency pool as Singleton.

Here is my common package class:

```
public class CustomConfiguration
{
    public LoggingConfiguration ConfigureLogger(bool fileLogging = false)
    {
        var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

        if (enableFileLogging)
        {
            var fileTarget = new FileTarget("fileTarget");
            fileTarget.FileName = "logs/log.txt";
            fileTarget.Layout = "${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} - ${message}";
            config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);
            config.AddRule(LogLevel.Debug, LogLevel.Fatal, fileTarget);
        }

        return config;
    }
}
```

In my `program.cs` file I am doing like below but it's not working:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();
builder.Logging.Services.AddSingleton<CustomConfiguration>();
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Host.UseNLog();

logger.Info("Service Init");
```

It not picking a setting that I defined on `CustomConfiguration`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can explicitely tell `NLog` to use `CustomConfiguration.ConfigureLogger` before registering `NLog` like this:

```
NLog.LogManager.Configuration = CustomConfiguration.ConfigureLogger();
// ...
builder.Host.UseNLog();
```

Not sure if it's possible to register that configuration for `NLog` to get it from DI [see Configuration in C# section for details](https://blog.elmah.io/nlog-tutorial-the-essential-guide-for-logging-from-csharp/) (just a reference I found), but if it is, I would assume it should be registered as `LoggerConfiguration` and inherit from that class.

Another possible solution to getting configured logger instance before builder.Build() is called (if this is what you need in this example) can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73466169/22083798).

Comment: do I need to inject the ```CustomConfiguration``` class ?

Comment: @rabnercasandra only if you want it for some other purposes (or/and in the methods called later). If it is used only for this single method, maybe it's better to make it `static` even.
But if you want to use some other properties of this class to get config settings dynamically, I believe you may want custom `NLoggerFactory` or logger.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change your `ConfigureLogger` to be a static extension method:

```cs
namespace NLog
{
    public static class CustomConfiguration
    {
        public static ISetupBuilder LoadConfigurationForApp(this NLog.Config.ISetupBuilder setupBuilder, bool fileLogging = false)
        {
           // setupBuilder.RegisterNLogWeb(); // NLog.Web.AspNetCore Layout-Renderers

           var config = new LoggingConfiguration(setupBuilder.LogFactory);

           if (fileLogging)
           {
             var fileTarget = new FileTarget("fileTarget");
             fileTarget.FileName = "logs/log.txt";
             fileTarget.Layout = "${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} - ${message}";
             config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);
             config.AddRule(LogLevel.Debug, LogLevel.Fatal, fileTarget);
           }

           setupBuilder.LogFactory.Configuration = config;
           return setupBuilder;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```cs
var logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationForApp().GetCurrentClassLogger();
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Host.UseNLog();  // Injects NLog as LoggingProvider for ILogger

logger.Info("Service Init");
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Fluent-Configuration-API